# html login form becoming too small in mobile view

Tags: html, css, forms, sass

i have a simple html form, which is working fine in desktop devices but not visible in mobile devices. my code is like below:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,500&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #9b59b6;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 20px 40px;
}

.header h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.form {
  padding: 30px 40px;
}

.form-control {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.form-control label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.form-control input {
  border: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: block;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-control input:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border-color: #777;
}

.form-control.success input {
  border-color: #2ecc71;
}

.form-control.error input {
  border-color: #e74c3c;
}

.form-control i {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 10px;
}

.form-control.success i.fa-check-circle {
  color: #2ecc71;
  visibility: visible;
}

.form-control.error i.fa-exclamation-circle {
  color: #e74c3c;
  visibility: visible;
}

.form-control small {
  color: #e74c3c;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.form-control.error small {
  visibility: visible;
}

.form button {
  background-color: #8e44ad;
  border: 2px solid #8e44ad;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}


/* SOCIAL PANEL CSS */

.social-panel-container {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 80px;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.social-panel-container.visible {
  transform: translateX(-10px);
}

.social-panel {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 16px 31px -17px rgba(0, 31, 97, 0.6);
  border: 5px solid #001F61;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Muli';
  position: relative;
  height: 169px;
  width: 370px;
  max-width: calc(100% - 10px);
}

.social-panel button.close-btn {
  border: 0;
  color: #97A5CE;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}

.social-panel button.close-btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.social-panel p {
  background-color: #001F61;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding: 2px 17px 6px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  width: 235px;
}

.social-panel p i {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.social-panel p a {
  color: #FF7500;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.social-panel h4 {
  margin: 20px 0;
  color: #97A5CE;
  font-family: 'Muli';
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.social-panel ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.social-panel ul li {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.social-panel ul li a {
  border: 1px solid #DCE1F2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #001F61;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.social-panel ul li a:hover {
  border-color: #FF6A00;
  box-shadow: 0 9px 12px -9px #FF6A00;
}

.floating-btn {
  border-radius: 26.5px;
  background-color: #001F61;
  border: 1px solid #001F61;
  box-shadow: 0 16px 22px -17px #03153B;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 999;
}

.floating-btn:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #001F61;
}

.floating-btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.floating-text {
  background-color: #001F61;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Muli';
  padding: 7px 15px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 998;
}

.floating-text a {
  color: #FF7500;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .social-panel-container.visible {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  .floating-btn {
    right: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
  </div>


  <form id="form" class="form" method="post" action="">
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="username">Full Name</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" name="name" id="username" />
      <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
      <small>Error message</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="username">Email</label>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email" />
      <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
      <small>Error message</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="username">Roll Number</label>
      <input type="text" maxlength="10" placeholder="Roll Number" name="rollnumber" id="password" />
      <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
      <small>Error message</small>
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

this is my live url: [enter link description here](https://badrukaonline.com/feepayment/)
when i view this in mobile, the form is too small, i have to zoom to see it properly, can anyone please tell me how to make this form fit to screen in all devices, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the container width styles like this

```
.container {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This is a responsive container for the contact form.

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by changing the "width" in your .container style

```css
.container {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 90%;
}
```

but the better solution is using MediaQuery to adjust the container style based on the screen size

Comment: i had tried this, this doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Try using (a bit more) static values, like em instead of percents, so it doesn't collapse. Been there, done that. One of the most annoying problems when designing :(